# Banach-Saks property and reflexivity

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

On the German Wikipedia page on the [Banach-Saks property](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach-Saks-Eigenschaft), they claim that every Banach space with the Banach-Saks property is reflexive but that the converse is not true. There should be a proof due to T. Nishiura and D. Waterman, but unfortunately, I can't find a proof of this interesting statement. It would be appreciated if someone could give me an online available reference (if possible).
Unfortunately, my library at the university doesn't have a copy.

Thx for your help

math

Comment: Studia Math. and Fund. Math. + a dozen other worthwhile series (such as Banach's collected works) can be found on the [homepage of the Polish Virtual Library](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/index.php?jez=en). It takes some time to get used to browsing these sites but it's worth it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is Nishiura and Waterman's paper.

> *Nishiura, T.; Waterman, D.*, [**Reflexivity and summability**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm-23-1-53-57), Stud. Math. 23, 53-57 (1963). [ZBL0121.09402](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0121.09402).

Albert Baernstein gives a counter-example for the converse in the paper:

> *Baernstein, Albert II*, [**On reflexivity and summability**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm-42-1-91-94), Stud. Math. 42, 91-94 (1972). [ZBL0228.46014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0228.46014).

Comment: Thx for your link! I just wanted to be sure that the reference on Wikipedia was correct.

Answer (score 8):

For the record: A Banach space $X$ has the *Banach-Saks* property if given a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ there is a subsequence $(y_n)$ of $(x_n)$ such that the sequence $(\sigma_n)=(n^{-1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n y_k)$ is norm convergent.

In Diestel's Sequences and Series in Banach spaces, the following outline for the proof that a Banach space with the Banach-Saks property is reflexive is given:

1) The Banach-Saks property is an isomorphic invariant.

2) If $X$ has the Banach-Saks property, then so do all of its closed linear subspaces.

3) $\ell_1$ does not have the Banach-Saks property.

4) If $(x_n)$ is weakly Cauchy and if ${\rm norm }\,\,\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{-1} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_n$ exists, then $(x_n)$ is weakly convergent.

5) Conclude that a space with the Banach Saks property is reflexive.

Note by Rosenthal's $\ell_1$ theorem (Every bounded sequence in the Banach space $X$ has a weakly Cauchy subsequence if and only if $X$ contains no isomorphic copy of $\ell_1$), if $X$ has the Banach-Saks property, then by 1), 2), and 3), every bounded sequence has a weakly Cauchy subsequence. From 4), then, it follows that every bounded sequence in $X$ has a weakly convergent subsequence.  Thus, the unit ball of $X$ is weakly compact by the Eberlein-Smulian Theorem; and so $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: Thx for your outline of the proof! But I accept the answer of Davide Giraudo, just because I needed the original paper of Nishiura and Waterman or another reference for a complete proof. I hope you understand. Nevertheless I upvoted also your answer.